# Default install of NextJS 13 (13.0.7) "app" method doesn't work

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm trying to create a brand new project using NextJS 13 to try out the new "app" folder approach. I use the following commands.

```bash
npx create-next-app@latest --experimental-app
npm run dev
```

With no other changes whatsoever, I get the error below shown in the browser when I try to browse to localhost:3000.

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')

Call Stack
options.factory
file:///D:/Projects/Personal/leeconlin-website/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (710:31)
__webpack_require__
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
file:///D:/Projects/Personal/leeconlin-website/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (365:21)
require
node_modules\next\dist\client\image.js (7:15)
./node_modules/next/dist/client/image.js
file:///D:/Projects/Personal/leeconlin-website/.next/static/chunks/app/page.js (39:1)
options.factory
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (710:31)
__webpack_require__
file:///D:/Projects/Personal/leeconlin-website/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (365:21)
__webpack_require__
node_modules\next\dist\client\app-index.js (26:16)
requireModule
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\client.js (142:0)
initializeModuleChunk
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\client.js (427:0)
readChunk
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\client.js (252:0)
mountLazyComponent
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23079:0)
beginWork
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (24792:0)
beginWork$1
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (32185:0)
performUnitOfWork
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (31082:0)
workLoopConcurrent
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (31068:0)
renderRootConcurrent
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (31026:0)
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (29983:0)
workLoop
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\scheduler\index.js (10:3921)
flushWork
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\scheduler\index.js (10:3629)
MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\scheduler\index.js (10:1811)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Tried to upgrade to Next 13 today and I'm also getting the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current solution is to use next.js 13.0.6, cause there's something wrong with 13.0.7.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@next/font": "13.0.6",
    "@types/node": "18.11.17",
    "@types/react": "18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.9",
    "eslint": "8.30.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.0.6",
    "next": "13.0.6",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.9.4"
  }
```

if you still have an error, please delete your `.next` folder and node_modules folder, run `npm i` and try again.

I found the solution here:
[TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call') on Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74832268/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-call-on-next-js)

Comment: Sorry, But it is not working