# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call') on Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm pretty new to Next.js and Typescript. I wanna build a project using next.js and typescript and tailwind CSS using this simple create app command:
`npx create-next-app -e with-tailwindcss my-project`

Everything just went fine until I wanted to use the Image tag using next/image and got an error

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')

Call Stack
options.factory
file:///C:/Users/irwan/Projects/messenger-clone/meta-messenger/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (710:31)
__webpack_require__
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
file:///C:/Users/irwan/Projects/messenger-clone/meta-messenger/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (365:21)
require
node_modules\next\dist\client\image.js (7:15)
./node_modules/next/dist/client/image.js
file:///C:/Users/irwan/Projects/messenger-clone/meta-messenger/.next/static/chunks/app/layout.js (39:1)
options.factory
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (710:31)
__webpack_require__
file:///C:/Users/irwan/Projects/messenger-clone/meta-messenger/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (365:21)
__webpack_require__
node_modules\next\dist\client\app-index.js (26:16)
requireModule
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\client.js (142:0)
initializeModuleChunk
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\client.js (427:0)
resolveModuleChunk
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\client.js (385:0)
eval
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\client.js (668:0)
```

I'm sure the error is not about the URL as I already added the domain to be whitelisted in my next.config.js file.

Here is my package JSON file:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^13.0.7",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.11.3",
    "@types/react": "18.0.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.6",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
    "postcss": "^8.4.18",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.1",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  }
}
```

Last I'm using the beta feature(?) appDir on next.js 13. Here is my next.config.js file:

```
reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    domains: ['i.ibb.co']
  },
  experimental: {
    appDir: true
  }
```

I'm using the image tag on my Header.tsx component. Here is my Header.tsx

```
import Image from "next/image";
import React from "react";

function Header() {
  const url = "https://i.ibb.co/LhMfkJw/logo-Meta.png";
  return (
    <header>
      <div>
        <div>
          <Image src={url} alt="Logo" width={50} height={10} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

And then use that header on my layout.tsx component:

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import Header from "./Header";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html>
      <head />
      <body>
        <Header />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Thanks for the reply

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include all the relevant code so we can assist you. Where are you using the `Image` component?

Comment: Hi @ivanatias, thanks for the reply. I'm adding relevant detail now on my thread.

Comment: Could you try to download the image and use the downloaded image instead of a link?

Comment: Hi. @Likepineapple I did try but it still threw the same error.

Comment: Can you create a GitHub repo with the code?

Comment: Hi @Likepineapple. Sure, and then what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally have some time to continue this project and as @Abdelrhman kamal mentioned that the usage of next/image can be solved by installing next canary:

```
npm install next@canary
```

May be it is already fixed in the update released as I previously use next version of 13.0.7 and the canary one is 13.1.1.

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

I also had this same problem please change ur next version to 13.0.6 and wait until we all get 13.0.8 or greater than that it is a problem in version 13.0.7

Comment: Still having this issue with version 13.0.6

Comment: please delete your .next folder and node_modules folder and run *npm i* and try again @NeuTronas

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This comment is True. i reverted back from 13.0.7 to 13.0.6 and that same error was gone.

Comment: I ran into this problem with Version 13.1.0. :/

Comment: try degrading the version @DataMastery

Comment: I also have this issue with version 14.0.3

Answer (score 6):

For those using `next-transpile-modules` — use `transpilePackages` option instead. This will resolve the issue for you.

The npm page says that this package is built-in in next 13.1
https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-transpile-modules

Comment: This fixed my issue, for those who are looking how to to use new prop, here is a link 
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/compiler#module-transpilation

Comment: this also fixed my isssue, which in my case was showing `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'and')`

Comment: Plus 1 this also helped me fix `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'and')` thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Remove all the service workers.

DevTools > Application > Storage > Clear site data

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what causes this, but doing an `npm install next@canary` solved this issue for me

Comment: Thankss, will be trying it.

Answer (score 1):

go to page.tsx or page.js and delete all Image components and everything will work fine
Edit#1
Use this command; it will fix that issue: npm install next@canary
next@canary is a next.js package that fixes issues and problems before moving on to the next.js version

Comment: :/ but how will we use Image component then?

Comment: at this point use (npm install next@canary) that will fix you issues

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This might be an issue with the internal SSR (server and client components) of Next 13. Try changing your client component from `import` to `const Components = dynamic(() => import("."), {ssr: false})`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the exact updates are. but `yarn add next@canary` or `npm install next@canary` worked for me. More information:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/docs/upgrading.md

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing my dev start command from `next dev` to `next dev --turbo`. Note that this only works on Next.js 14

Edit: this happened again and I was able to resolve the issue by unregistering the service worker I had on my website through the chrome devtools and then hard reloading the page.