# Nextjs13 'Link' Tag issue, Is there configuration required?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I just created a NextJS 13 default application by using the following command.

```
npx create-next-app@latest --experimental-app

<Link> is not working.
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')
```

What am I missing? I have not written any code except for

```
 <>
    <h1 className='text-3xl font-bold underline'>
      Hello my friends
    </h1>

    <Link href='/'>Click Me</Link>
    <Image alt=''></Image>
    </>
```

I maybe missing a step in configuration. No clue.

Comment: I continued looking on stack overflow and have found the solution.
NextJs 13.0.7 has a bug and to fix it we can use the command npm i next@canary

My <Link> tag is working now. Solutions is provided by Abdelrhman kamal -> https://stackoverflow.com/users/17442737/abdelrhman-kamal and the post is this oen -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74832268/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-call-on-next-js
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you've found a solution to the problem, please post it as an answer rather than a comment.