# "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'foundTicket')". getTickets()(fetch from MongoDB by Mongoose) works, but getTicketById() not

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, next.js, runtime-error

I'm new to next.js and making this project following an youtuber, here you can find my code: https://github.com/Fanguiee/ticketing-app/tree/edit-existing-item
or you can also read below.Thanks in advance:)

Screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0W0k.png)
Error in text:

```
 ⨯ app\TicketPage\[id]\page.jsx (30:40) @ foundTicket
 ⨯ TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'foundTicket')
    at TicketPage (./app/TicketPage/[id]/page.jsx:35:45)
  28 |   } else {
  29 |     updateTicketData = await getTicketById(params.id);
> 30 |     updateTicketData = updateTicketData.foundTicket;
     |                                        ^
  31 |   }
  32 |   return <TicketForm ticket={updateTicketData} />;
  33 | };
```

app\TicketPage[id]\page.jsx:

```
import TicketForm from "@/app/(components)/TicketForm";

const getTicketById = async (id) => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/Tickets/${id}`, {
      method: "GET",
      cache: "no-store",
    });

    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Failed to fetch Ticket by id ${id} .`);
    }
    console.log("Ah!");
    console.log(res);
    return res.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const TicketPage = async ({ params }) => {
  const EDITMODE = params.id === "new" ? false : true; //Tickecpage/new or TicketPage/123?
  let updateTicketData = {};
  if (!EDITMODE) {
    updateTicketData = {
      _id: "new",
    };
  } else {
    updateTicketData = await getTicketById(params.id);
    updateTicketData = updateTicketData.foundTicket;
  }
  return <TicketForm ticket={updateTicketData} />;
};

export default TicketPage;
```

app\api\Tickets[id]\route.js:

```
import TicketForm from "@/app/(components)/TicketForm";

const getTicketById = async (id) => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/Tickets/${id}`, {
      method: "GET",
      cache: "no-store",
    });

    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Failed to fetch Ticket by id ${id} .`);
    }
    console.log("Ah!");
    console.log(res);
    return res.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const TicketPage = async ({ params }) => {
  const EDITMODE = params.id === "new" ? false : true; //Tickecpage/new or TicketPage/123?
  let updateTicketData = {};
  if (!EDITMODE) {
    updateTicketData = {
      _id: "new",
    };
  } else {
    updateTicketData = await getTicketById(params.id);
    updateTicketData = updateTicketData.foundTicket;
  }
  return <TicketForm ticket={updateTicketData} />;
};

export default TicketPage;
```

i have node.js :v18.16.0, have problem updating it:( maybe it is the problem?

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ticketing-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.16",
    "eslint": "8.52.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^14.0.0",
    "mongodb": "^6.2.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.6.3",
    "next": "^13.0.8",
    "postcss": "8.4.31",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.5"
  }
}
```

First i used next.js 14.0.0 and then tried older version after reading the post [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call') on Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74832268/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-call-on-next-js)

(next.js 13.0.8 in package.json(but somehow the actual version is Next.js v13.5.6).The Youtuber from whom i learned this project used "next": "13.4.13",should i try that version maybe??)

i also tried `npm install next@canary`, but it didnt help.

---

i have:

```
const getTickets = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/Tickets/", {
      cache: "no-store",
    });
    return res.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Failed to get tickets.", error);
  }
};
```

**which works totally fine**, i use this function to display all the tickets. It's really strange that the function getTicketById() does't work.

Comment: `getTicketById` returns `undefined`, hence why you get the error about trying to get a property off `undefined` in the next line.

Comment: I know, but i dont know how to fix it. The id in the http adresse exists in my database and  database query works fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to make sure the file you fetched by ID exists before accessing the attribute:

```
updateTicketData = await getTicketById(params.id);
updateTicketData = updateTicketData?.foundTicket;
```

this should put `undefined` inside `updateTicketData` if `updateTicketData` doesn't exists

Answer (score -1):

I assume that everything in the 'getTicketById' function works fine. I believe the issue is that we can't pass the data from RSC to the component without it being in JSON format. You can try the following:

```js
else {
    const data = await getTicketById(params.id);
    updateTicketData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringfy(updateTicketData));
}
```

Hope, it works.